# Can someone help me with this Pedigree Analysis?

Tags: genetics, pedigree

$\text{So... here is the given pedigree chart:}$

[image: Ped1]

> My question is ... whether this is an autosomal or a X-linked recessive trait.

---

The book I was following gave me this info:

[image: Ped2]

---

**My Attempt:**

Looking at the chart ... it all comes down to either X-linked recessive or Autosomal recessive.

According to Rule 1. under these conditions:

1. If it appears with equal frequency in both Males and Females -- Autosomal
2. Otherwise , if more male than female -- X-linked

> *But my teacher said ... "its not always so"*

So.... I tried with both once (brute force method ... going through all possibilities) and I could not understand which one...

It seems both are correct (which obviously is not possible)

So can anyone please help me with this problem!?

Thanks!

Comment: Are squares males and circle females?

Comment: It is both possible that the trait is x-linked recessive and autosomal recessive. If autosomal recessive, that would require individual 12 to be heterozygous though.

Comment: @Remi.b Yes ... and the darkened ones are the affected ones

Comment: The rule is you have to see 1st if the pedigree obeys Y-liked inheritance, if not then whether dominant/recessive. Once you figure out that (say it turned out to be recessive) see if it obeys X-linked or not. If it does the pedigree shows **X-lined(recessive) trait**. If it doesn't then it is autosomal and applying the genotypes you'll see there's no conflict and it obeys Autosomal inheritance for sure. The list of characters they are not always true for all pedigree charts, you'll find some matching while others may not.

Comment: I would suggest you to consult your teacher because it is next to impossible to explain in a written Q&A format. Besides there are a number of ways this is taught, learning from more than one source will actually confuse you.

Comment: Looking through the table you provided, X-linked recessive trait seems the most plausible, since almost all of the conditions are precisely fulfilled. The only one that seems to challenge this conclusion is number 4: "is never passed from father to son". This is tricky because of the relationship between no. 4 and no. 7. However, this doesn't necessarily rules out X-linked recessive, since it is possible that no. 7's mother (no. 3) is a carrier and no. 7 got a defective X chromosome from her. We don't have her history, but this is possible and makes X-linked recessive a plausible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the currently given information both autosomal and X-linked recessive is possible:

**(WARNING extremely sloppy Paint editing ahead)**

This is a possible scenario for an autosomal recessive trait:
[image: Autosomal gene inheritance]

And this is one for a X-linked trait:
[image: X-linked gene inheritance]

Ideally you would extend the chart until you encounter a scenario where an affected female has healthy male offspring (which indicates an autosomal trait).

Comment: For both autosomal and X-linked recessive, we must make the assumption that 3 is heterozygous. The genotype of 1 shouldn't matter in either case, and is most likely homozygous.

Comment: Oops you are absolutely right

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my answer. You're absolutely right and, actually, the entire answer is now wrong.

Comment: @canadianer I suppose X-linked might still be slightly more likely as autosomal assumes subject 12 to be a heterozygous outsider.